# How to remove an element from an array in redisgraph

Tags: redis, cypher, redisgraph

## How to remove an element from an array in redisgraph

Consider the below data in the redisgraph database.

`graph.query Test "MATCH (u:Person) Create (:Person {address:['something1', 'something2']})"`

I need to remove `something1` from the address list.

How can we achieve by writing a cypher query in redisgraph database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following query, it will remove element at position 4 (0 base indexing)

```
127.0.0.1:6379> GRAPH.QUERY g "WITH [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] AS arr RETURN arr[..4] + arr[5..]"
1) 1) arr[..4] + arr[5..]
2) 1) 1) "[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @SWilly22
Is there any way to remove an element directly from array apart from INDEXED based removal of an attribute? some thing like below
`graph.query Test "MATCH (n:Person) WHERE EXISTS (n.address) REMOVE "something1" IN n.address`

Comment: Consider the following query:

WITH ['a', 'b', 'c'] AS arr UNWIND range(0, size(arr)) AS idx WITH arr, idx WHERE arr[idx] = 'b' RETURN arr[0..idx] + arr[idx+1..]

Comment: Thank you very much @SWilly22 this helps.